# Setup 301 redirect for .html pages Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

Hi I have migrated my store from Magento to Wordpress, I want to set up 301 redirects for the product pages they were /product.html but now are just /product I used the following code in the .htaccess file, which works but it makes the homepage break, how can I alter this code to make the homepage still work?

redirectMatch 301 ^(.*).html$ $1

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the index page:

```
redirectMatch 301 ^(?!/index\.html$)(.*)\.html$ $1
```

Comment: thanks, I have now tried that but when I type in my homepage, the url changes from example.com to example.com/index and comes up with a 404 not found page?

Comment: still cant get t to work, just says page cannot be found for the homepage